# Why the following set of ODEs is not integrated?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Consider the following dataset:

```
    Data1 = {{0.04000000000000001, 3.6730181515774437*^-19, 
  0.0011366457254822827, 60968.11540339052, 2.1236323916037964*^-14, 
  0.000024533464278266223, 
     6.05793658772411*^-10}, {0.04286077220950427, 
  3.5735320748337414*^-18, 0.0011367866249206487, 74019.86038013306, 
  9.44320381587328*^-13, 
     0.000029966921646068634, 
  6.061648458859923*^-10}, {0.045926144859875326, 
  3.255424981728174*^-17, 0.0011369527269621297, 90053.88090726305, 
     3.286154294358077*^-11, 0.00003658039668686287, 
  6.070080518990282*^-10}, {0.049210750832495286, 
  2.5341104165796417*^-16, 0.0011371790768826945, 
     109594.1604424725, 9.081851407892915*^-10, 
  0.00004461671001039301, 6.085482546231459*^-10}, 
   {0.05273026954225631, 1.7149288047460928*^-15, 
  0.00113750204533264, 133531.87119944708, 2.0260455365402744*^-8, 
  0.00005562012741315951, 
     6.109252168769861*^-10}, {0.056501501784910174, 
  1.050519972446482*^-14, 0.001137926591272428, 163230.9619786704, 
  3.7090463605171533*^-7, 
     0.00006760933834508163, 
  6.144275485232054*^-10}, {0.06054244993744833, 
  5.785126177289693*^-14, 0.0011385002529520187, 199962.7324694581, 
     5.640895974410171*^-6, 0.00008210446936595845, 
  6.198175525381558*^-10}, {0.06487240389435721, 
  2.859704227057019*^-13, 0.001139310302677116, 
     246401.4495066501, 0.00007243730639484008, 
  0.0000996480849338258, 6.276535512220924*^-10}, 
   {0.06951203314997503, 1.2815620129762066*^-12, 
  0.0011405130800622618, 304616.8073825221, 0.0007925881290266281, 
  0.00012307121962089226, 
     6.380388322973216*^-10}, {0.07448348546651472, 
  5.269337715555936*^-12, 0.0011422281493432716, 379248.5567463476, 
  0.0074986358256308484, 
     0.00014928353005425407, 
  6.520750615794034*^-10}, {0.07981049259875521, 
  2.0074747616321736*^-11, 0.0011447257370502235, 474876.1413831532, 
     0.0618888614669688, 0.00018435323587895211, 
  6.700559990103894*^-10}, {0.08551848358008932, 
  7.05124504406454*^-11, 0.0011484669669138883, 
     598564.5009744188, 0.4502465359405161, 0.00022438799313786295, 
  6.925085322975094*^-10}, {0.09163470611071092, 
  2.3000740431526548*^-10, 
     0.0011540447823168796, 760828.7492393866, 2.9182068721657934, 
  0.0002785357086817402, 7.197104737969417*^-10}, 
   {0.09818835662740127, 7.024316848540299*^-10, 
  0.001162170287551631, 972405.9236193274, 16.94107794443051, 
  0.0003412477750141644, 
     7.520866142933496*^-10}, {0.10521071967581529, 
  2.0151537395464318*^-9, 0.0011739104100202753, 
  1.247297115624304*^6, 88.60424433247508, 
     0.0004271343315385529, 
  7.89111870149623*^-10}, {0.11273531725057817, 
  5.392959664617988*^-9, 0.0011917089463320113, 1.610428841403897*^6, 
     421.76716793957445, 0.0005373848560522533, 
  8.311068757370129*^-10}, {0.12079806881608067, 
  1.3662948531145418*^-8, 0.0012170983752536689, 
     2.088091105249584*^6, 1835.2807668292667, 0.0006794866268582713, 
  8.777148336817495*^-10}, 
   {0.12943746277185134, 3.26800243113598*^-8, 0.0012539678437698998, 
  2.7100656444720207*^6, 7322.4230773758245, 0.0008439764753236527, 
     9.2792356664838*^-10}, {0.13869474018101272, 
  7.424990724058318*^-8, 0.0013074352824174532, 
  3.5319312976799784*^6, 27030.38887883136, 
     0.00107442884253638, 
  9.813608946416635*^-10}, {0.14861409163886904, 
  1.6118549524558457*^-7, 0.0013834701962826016, 4.601653981863014*^6, 
     92413.4995937878, 0.001372210710456111, 
  1.0374440262624992*^-9}, {0.15924286822139894, 
  3.359117261965592*^-7, 0.001490640368191695, 
     6.003178262294154*^6, 294588.19867804437, 0.0017135443780015402, 
  1.0953659562222803*^-9}, 
   {0.1706318075206371, 6.768144438289502*^-7, 0.0016418145327914294, 
  7.818396651581257*^6, 877127.4857127845, 0.002195205293756092, 
     1.1534507078566864*^-9}, {0.18283527584595002, 
  1.3253825227723483*^-6, 0.0018530825010397774, 
  1.019158194753562*^7, 2.456545832150365*^6, 
     0.0028160341031557017, 
  1.2118127587928474*^-9}, {0.1959115277473785, 
  2.541882634404852*^-6, 0.00214520506148593, 1.3264692068722617*^7, 
     6.482556887839657*^6, 0.003519077495772852, 
  1.2698477884419106*^-9}, {0.2099229840999091, 
  4.7973894775465834*^-6, 0.0025485871023961408, 
     1.7206929419349123*^7, 1.6151997002525678*^7, 
  0.004514855063665674, 1.3254573346580083*^-9}, 
   {0.2249365300761397, 8.938280979270732*^-6, 0.0031021976669112004, 
  2.23159353128588*^7, 3.825493075573033*^7, 0.0057928643041654975, 
     1.3796925661487545*^-9}, {0.24102383442974318, 
  0.000016491104414852177, 0.0038603290769480118, 
  2.8896676575433616*^7, 8.629961187526782*^7, 
     0.007222131323891681, 
  1.431134731390959*^-9}, {0.25826169161386225, 
  0.00003013498762673002, 0.004891523184322172, 3.732919279303819*^7, 
     1.8586729491043442*^8, 0.009252005938239705, 
  1.4797712109910823*^-9}, {0.27673238836757463, 
  0.00005453864812818399, 0.00629183641986388, 
     4.820132037437235*^7, 3.840485105566199*^8, 
  0.011509316021565116, 1.5253491942476746*^-9}, 
   {0.2965240965203671, 0.00009761820733772267, 0.008186960442081337, 
  6.211483068339884*^7, 7.62191350054374*^8, 0.014713128474094301, 
     1.567646943405622*^-9}, {0.3177312938897126, 
  0.00017278324797833004, 0.010754393209756815, 7.995070777156478*^7, 
  1.4578452750520904*^9, 
     0.018257113197046024, 
  1.6064948687755004*^-9}, {0.34045521528095063, 
  0.00030185339768827715, 0.014218998372583154, 1.0280561154606108*^8, 
     2.694270360773067*^9, 0.023286894279490714, 
  1.6425896937056255*^-9}, {0.364804335742364, 0.0005209611648465304, 
  0.018911113696050464, 
     1.3198929410199991*^8, 4.819255315060689*^9, 
  0.028823919766414487, 1.6745715437867294*^-9}, 
   {0.3908948883823244, 0.0008861421412744314, 0.025231897306304558, 
  1.6937248053716332*^8, 8.369218172915381*^9, 0.035646186421712, 
     1.704347805240533*^-9}, {0.41885141922035996, 
  0.0014879128934780943, 0.03377408680912669, 2.170856889094142*^8, 
  1.412863001652607*^10, 
     0.045300933483077885, 
  1.7306844074866155*^-9}, {0.44880738172078555, 
  0.002466286434495853, 0.04531709865432165, 2.779592325864481*^8, 
     2.3232109573694702*^10, 0.05589725905096408, 
  1.7541752035026805*^-9}, {0.48090577384696537, 
  0.004035550166444166, 0.06090375420869664, 
     3.557989441565829*^8, 3.729891184286874*^10, 0.068922502945096, 
  1.7758023178809883*^-9}, 
   {0.5152998206772536, 0.0065283544138783406, 0.08200914283817416, 
  4.551490366083445*^8, 5.8540824576103294*^10, 0.08732573942051954, 
     1.7944955878185098*^-9}, {0.552153705841154, 
  0.010447781138129195, 0.11062036290904508, 5.814525939360955*^8, 
  8.98880028939501*^10, 
     0.107473843263601, 1.810895200404476*^-9}, {0.5916433552672831, 
  0.01653890680422021, 0.14935730557017074, 7.429912935755776*^8, 
     1.3543097497648143*^11, 0.13219796597640998, 
  1.8258944804728217*^-9}, {0.6339572769844455, 0.025937307600763675, 
  0.20196184017845184, 
     9.485638471332476*^8, 2.0024824008527032*^11, 
  0.16711888122276794, 1.8392419060443485*^-9}, 
   {0.6792974609846979, 0.04034700409506356, 0.2736029058694903, 
  1.2102237755567687*^9, 2.909885449151632*^11, 0.2052666582315007, 
     1.8501160265376655*^-9}, {0.7278803434439935, 
  0.06223137927350765, 0.37105306369630586, 1.542952475743961*^9, 
  4.160021805634737*^11, 
     0.25202295914652556, 
  1.8600321208203338*^-9}, {0.7799378399032184, 0.09523449582533373, 
  0.5037214290466892, 1.967536927419406*^9, 
     5.862404551266245*^11, 0.30932363965331905, 
  1.8691156000495226*^-9}, {0.8357184523416157, 0.14480564158746242, 
  0.6849656687466679, 
     2.505864555324614*^9, 8.139905161351083*^11, 
  0.39012767685654065, 1.876773077518704*^-9}, 
   {0.8954884554273358, 0.21895982027010316, 0.933214460922383, 
  3.724151664300324*^8, 1.3022394818294788*^11, 0.4783452882352051, 
     1.8829132235127783*^-9}, {0.9595331676077962, 
  0.32904532742184267, 1.272684547155989, 0., 0., 0.5863801024968948, 
  1.8885541302790296*^-9}, 
   {1.0281583131075456, 0.491691526418462, 1.737372694863958, 0., 0., 
  0.7186826843829303, 1.893783649743893*^-9}, 
   {1.1016914813352667, 0.7314024765782356, 2.375371032564205, 0., 
  0., 0.9051296290287619, 1.89819938884556*^-9}, 
   {1.1804836906665546, 1.084143824031097, 3.2543622222297746, 0., 
  0., 1.1085674226849835, 1.901325085222587*^-9}, 
   {1.264911064067352, 1.5998883370347974, 4.462773587712801, 0., 0., 
  1.3575721723418253, 1.904266253623223*^-9}, 
   {1.3553766245568106, 2.3514114854853303, 6.125519165240608, 0., 
  0., 1.6623947188858716, 1.9070847187327836*^-9}, 
   {1.4523122190804059, 3.443728902375022, 8.416725997772431, 0., 0., 
  2.0354856022589813, 1.9098278742932196*^-9}, 
   {1.5561805799771222, 5.032516360409247, 11.588651462598817, 0., 
  0., 2.560427181523345, 1.91113941530246*^-9}, 
   {1.6674775338813417, 7.33214391965452, 15.971903907103549, 0., 0., 
  3.1336127451840485, 1.912418218615513*^-9}, 
   {1.7867343686038526, 10.650675858898598, 22.029553714476762, 0., 
  0., 3.8350032698731886, 1.9137576280470963*^-9}, 
   {1.9145203692905537, 15.42848919710927, 30.406219045113726, 0., 
  0., 4.693382379212429, 1.9151902699813277*^-9}, 
   {2.0514455359654598, 22.307933788089844, 42.025296542578594, 0., 
  0., 5.901791123092204, 1.916091945714172*^-9}, 
   {2.198163495430499, 32.2024768282308, 58.16590582996733, 0., 0., 
  7.220190907338247, 1.9163661828847035*^-9}, 
   {2.3553746214223565, 46.38277596899167, 80.55347510295799, 0., 0., 
  8.833153973418863, 1.916815241910244*^-9}, 
   {2.5238293779207726, 66.66321598076935, 111.60824528756592, 0., 
  0., 10.806958855072507, 1.917460271190991*^-9}, 
   {2.704331901567927, 95.63932394751524, 154.73396954520854, 0., 0., 
  13.22196478822141, 1.9183224443280263*^-9}, 
   {2.89774384029996, 137.07433730712353, 214.81009502241022, 0., 0., 
  16.619302561317976, 1.9181898557929484*^-9}, 
   {3.104988466514767, 196.1806402623078, 298.4252892891094, 0., 0., 
  20.32801520638921, 1.918113460817766*^-9}, 
   {3.3270550844106843, 280.2875974453487, 414.6818354793054, 0., 0., 
  24.86543724283311, 1.918293258915911*^-9}, 
   {3.5650037525349827, 399.7939118353185, 576.321713145112, 0., 0., 
  30.417780148740146, 1.9187389207216093*^-9}, 
   {3.819970344085745, 569.6278736669964, 801.4852301693955, 0., 0., 
  38.23525046862454, 1.9191330343923305*^-9}, 
   {4.0931719691230155, 811.0975018471803, 1115.8267571796891, 0., 
  0., 46.762378621512134, 1.918730838682514*^-9}, 
   {4.385912784572741, 1153.3316551215432, 1553.6000912931834, 0., 
  0., 57.19531021750488, 1.9186088593139887*^-9}, 
   {4.699590219758118, 1637.6511861862862, 2162.97753372881, 0., 0., 
  69.95978712026677, 1.918774068782407*^-9}, 
   {5.035701647176671, 2322.235219808318, 3011.0662706314047, 0., 0., 
  85.57904613887125, 1.9192315658181652*^-9}, 
   {5.395851530366614, 3291.2413919769583, 4195.0990748257955, 0., 
  0., 107.56017693667187, 1.9191750141203098*^-9}};
```

I interpolate them:

```
jacobian[T_] = 
  Interpolation[Data1[[All, {1, 6}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][T];
\[CapitalGamma]pn[T_] = 
  Interpolation[Data1[[All, {1, 2}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][T];
\[CapitalGamma]np[T_] = 
  Interpolation[Data1[[All, {1, 3}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][T];
\[CapitalGamma]npTod\[Gamma][T_] = 
  Interpolation[Data1[[All, {1, 4}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][T];
\[CapitalGamma]d\[Gamma]Tonp[T_] = 
  Interpolation[Data1[[All, {1, 5}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][T];
\[Eta]Bv[T_] = 
  Interpolation[Data1[[All, {1, 7}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][T];
```

Then I want to solve a set of differential equations:

```
XdDynamics[Xn_, Xd_, T_] = 
  Xn*(1 - Xn - Xd)*\[CapitalGamma]npTod\[Gamma][T] - 
   Xd*\[Eta]Bv[T]^-1*\[CapitalGamma]d\[Gamma]Tonp[T];
XnDynamics[Xn_, Xd_, T_] = (1 - Xn - Xd) \[CapitalGamma]pn[T] - 
   Xn*\[CapitalGamma]np[T] - XdDynamics[Xn, Xd, T];
    sol = NDSolve[{D[Xn[T], T]*
         jacobian[T] == -XnDynamics[Xn[T], Xd[T], T], 
       D[Xd[T], T]*jacobian[T] == -XdDynamics[Xn[T], Xd[T], T], 
       Xd[4.9] == 0, Xn[4.9] == 0.5}, {Xn, Xd}, {T, 0.04, 4.9}]
    f = Xn /. sol[[1]]
```

However, Mathematica says

```
NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at T == 0.841822; unable to continue
```

The point 0.8418... is the maximal point when the functions `\[CapitalGamma]npTod\[Gamma], \[CapitalGamma]npTod\[Gamma]` are non-zero.

Could you please tell me how to avoid this error?

P.S. Changing the method to StiffnessSwitching removes the error. However, the solution behaves badly, so this, unfortunately, does not help.

P.P.S. It seems that decreasing MaxStepSize matters. I've set MaxStepSize -> 0.5*10^-4, and the solution has been obtained. However, it now requires much more time for solving. This will increase the solving time after increasing the number of equations. Is there any alternative method of getting the solution without spending such an amount of time?

Comment: First, I get a different error, `NDSolve::ndsz`. Second when I try, `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` (suggested by the error), it works.  (V12.1.1, Mac)

Comment: @MichaelE2 : excuse me, initially I have copied an incorrect piece of code. Now the code is correct.

Comment: If the solution behaves badly, it may be that the code or data is in error.  By the way, the definitions of `XdDynamics` and `XnDynamics` differ in two blocks of coce.

Comment: @bbgodfrey : corrected the code problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey : it seems that decreasing MaxStepSize matters. I've set MaxStepSize -> 0.5*10^-4, and the solution has been obtained.

Comment: These problems are due to the enormous abrupt changes in your data just below `T = 1`, which you could point out in the question.    Running the computation to that point and only then reducing the time step could save you a factor of five or so in runtime.  `WhenEvent` also might help, although I am not sure how.  By the way, I needed `, MaxStepSize -> 10^-5` to avoid error messages.

Comment: @John, I think my method is wrong. If you decrease `MaxStepSize` on it, the solution converges to other one.